# Scraping Javascript webpage (script error occurred)

Tags: vb.net, web-scraping

I am scraping a dynamic webpage which is a javascript based webpage. I have done codes which is used to load the webpage first in the program:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.changiairport.com/flight-info/flight-status/passenger-departures")

End Sub
```

However, each time I run the program, script errors will pop up. Here is one of the example of the script error occurring:

An error has occurred in the script on this page.

Line: 0

Char: 0

Error:Script error

Code: 0

URL: http://s7.addthis.com/js/250/addthis_widget.js#pub=xa-4ae19b0b35192b8e

How should I do to eliminate the script errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
WebBrowser.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
```

property.

Details: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.scripterrorssuppressed%28v=vs.110%29.aspx